# Use Laravel Nova Filter for Metric?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a Filter configured for my Nova Resource. It applies the status:

```
public function apply(Request $request, $query, $value)
{
    return $query->where('status', $value);
}
```

This works fine for the Table, but I have some Metrics configured on the Index as well. Is there a way for me the apply the active filter also on the Metric itself?

The is the Calculate method:

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
{
    // apply the active Filter on this
    return $this->count($request, Intake::class, 'type');
}
```

Comment: I think this other question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035962/laravel-nova-metrics-filtering

Comment: something like this? https://novapackages.com/packages/square1-io/nova-metrics

Answer (score -2):

You can replace `Intake::class` with a Builder object.

```
return $this->count($request, Intake::where('active', 1), 'type');
```

Comment: That doesn't do a thing with the filter.